# UITableView reloadData and @catch block

Tags: ios, uitableview, try-catch

`[UITableView reloadData]` not called in @catch block

this is my code:

```
@try {
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
@catch (NSException *exeption) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Sometimes problems appears when inserting new rows in tableview (it doesn't matter which exactly) and I would like to handle it. While I testing exception raises @catch block handles it and crash not happens, but reloadData also not calling. I also tried to call reloadData on main thread manually with `perfomSelectorOnMainThread:` and GCD:

```
@catch (NSException *exeption) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

but it also didn't give any effect. Can somebody suggest something? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C, it's not a good idea to catch the exception and keep going. It's better to figure out what's wrong and prevent the exception from happening.

But for whatever reason, you can try `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

```
[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

---

**Update**

`-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` always runs in a later [run loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) even when the delay is 0.

```
[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

The effect is to call the `-reloadData` method in the next run loop. This is useful when there are UI changes are pending in the current run loop.

Comment: Whats the difference between `[self.tableView reloadData]` and `[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData)]` ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d There is no difference between `[self.tableView reloadData]` and `[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData)]`. There is however a difference between `[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData)]` and `[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]`.

Comment: I tried this in the catch block (both [self.tableView reloadData] and [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]) but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ordinaryman09 I'm not sure what the issue you encountering is. Post you problem as a new question.

Comment: Ok. I have the exact same issue, I have 
catch (NSException *exeption) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}

but this didn't do anything, so I tried your approach I added 
catch (NSException *exeption) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]
    });
}
and it still didn't do any update/refresh
Here's my thread I created:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945098/uitableview-reloaddata-within-catch-block