# UITableView reloadData within catch block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm trying to add a catch block within the UITableView but it doesn't do anything.

```
[self.dataArray addObject:@"xyz"];
@try {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    //try with nil to go to catch block
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:nil withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates]; 
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
}
```

Any advise on how to reload tableview in case there's a fail within the update? thanks!

**Update**

So I can handle if the insertRowsAtIndexPaths:nil
**This works**

```
@try {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    //try with nil to go to catch block
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:nil withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates]; 
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
}
```

However, the catch handler can't handle if the indexPath is -1 or out of bounds, and I'm getting this error:
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (60) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (60), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

**This doesn't work**

```
@try {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    //try with nil to go to catch block
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates]; 
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
}
```

The reason why I'm doing this is because I'm trying to debug this issue why this failed in the first place, but in the meantime, I want to recover from this issue and just refresh the table instead of crashing the app. Is there any way to **undo insertRowsAtIndexPaths** if it failed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the `@catch` to see if it is getting triggered?

Comment: yes, it did get triggerred

Comment: Then the tableview must be getting refreshed. Is your data source being updated properly? If there is an actual problem, it isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: Consolidate your code that an exception could never occur (this is possible). Btw: `begin- / endUpdates` is syntactic sugar in this case. It has no effect at all.

Comment: There is an issue with the animation which I'm still trying to debug:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906641/uitableview-missing-cell-for-newly-visible-row-nsinternalinconsistencyexception/43907858#43907858

In the meantime, I'd like the app not crashing and load the data, even without the animation. Thanks.

Comment: before you add a new object into your `dataArray`, please check whether or not there is an existing object already. If not, then first you need to initialize it.

Comment: right, I initialize the dataArray within the viewDidLoad